# .net WebAPI webapp: How to support Client Certificate Authentication and Microsoft Identity Authentication with either-or?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core-webapi

We have a WebAPI webapp which should support authentication via client certificate and authentication via Microsoft Identity/OAuth2. With our current implementation, it seems that the Microsoft Identity Authentication overrules the Client Certificate Authentication. If we just add the Microsoft Identity Authentication in first place, then the overruling behaves the opposite round.

The Program.cs for authentication looks currently like this:

```
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    
    // 1. setup Certificate Authentication
    builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CertificateAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddCertificate(options =>
    {
        // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/certauth
        options.AllowedCertificateTypes = CertificateTypes.All;
    
        options.Events = new CertificateAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnCertificateValidated = context =>
            {
                var claims = new[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, context.ClientCertificate.Subject, ClaimValueTypes.String, context.Options.ClaimsIssuer),
    
                    // since with that authentication we have no retrieved authorization from anywhere, we set it explicitly - for now ...
                    new Claim("scp", "GeneralScope")
                };
                context.Principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, context.Scheme.Name));
                context.Success();
    
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            },
            OnChallenge = x =>
            {
                return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
        };
    });
    builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        options.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(opts =>
        {
            opts.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate;
            opts.ClientCertificateValidation = (cert, chain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                // TODO validate certificate
                return true;
            };
        });
    });
    
    
    // 2. setup Microsoft Identity Authentication
    var jwtAuthentication = builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    jwtAuthentication.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
    jwtAuthentication.AddAppServicesAuthentication();

....

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.MapControllers();

    app.Run();
```

Dont be confused about the sloppy client certificate validation, this is still work in progress.

How do we need to change the code so we can have the two authentication modes along each other with a either-or way?

Comment: You can't.  The certificate is part of TLS (encrypted message) which occurs before the HTTPS request is sent.  The AUTH2 is performed on the decrypted request using tokens.  If HTTPS is required than AUTH2 will not work if the TLS fails.  IF HTTPS is not required than if AUTH2 fails there is not OR to then try TLS.  What may work is first send a HTTP and see if AUTH2 works.  Then if HTTP fails retry using HTTPS.  The server has to be configured to make HTTPS not required and not to use AUTH2 with HTTPS.

Comment: Hmm, I would say, the Client Certificate Authentication is not really related to TLS, because that for, the server provides already a certificate. When using Client Certificate Authentication, the certificate itself is transferd as a HTTP header value. Do we mix up here something?

Comment: Why do you think the client certificate is sent as a header?  The Client certificate is just limiting the TLS certificate to a specific certificate.  Normally the server with TLS send a certificate block with a list of certificate names and then client looks up names in stores.  The certificate in the code just forces the client to use only one certificate.

Comment: You are right, I thought, I had seen such a thing in postman, seems not :). So with a Client Certificate, this one is used for TLS instead of the Server certificate, right? However, my code does not implicitly requires a client certificate (opts.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate), so it would switch back to server certificate anyway in https mode. But could I not just remember, if the certificate was checked in first place as valid, so I could skip the OAuth2 authentication?

Comment: The certificate must be loaded in both the client and server for TLS to work.  The certificate itself is not transferred, only the name is passed.  All you code does is to use the specified certificate rather than any other certificate that is in the certificate block.  The OAuth2 is used after the connection is completed and gives limited access to the server based on the tokens.  So even if TLS passes you still need to get permission to access the server using the tokens.

Comment: Ok, I understand. My test with the Client Certificate worked only, because I had Client and Server on the same machine, both had access to the selected certificate, I wasn't aware of this behavior, thanks. Too bad, I cannot overrule the OAuth2 authentication, because if I knew, that a previous provided Client Certificate would be ok, I could just say: "Yes, it's ok, let him pass ..."